# How does someone read this notation for a proof?

Tags: notation

I've seen this notation in both logic and math and have yet to find a resource that talks about reading it. There's usually a line in between that intersects the two horizontally.

Notation:
$$\frac{\Gamma,A,B,\Pi \longrightarrow \Delta}{\Gamma,B,A,\Pi \longrightarrow \Delta}$$

Here's where I grabbed this from. I couldn't copy a picture so I just found a pdf and copied it over: http://math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/handbookI/ChapterI.pdf

Comment: Did you see the explanation on p. 11?

Comment: Holy crap, no I didn't. Wow, ironic that the one thing I choose to cite as an example has the solution in it. Thanks dude.